# CSS Añadir más de un elemento a la vez en nth-child

Tags: css

En CSS necesito asignar la misma propiedad al primer y el segundo elemento de una lista utilizando nth-child, ¿cuál sería la forma más breve de hacerlo?
gracias!

Comment: Hola Jonatan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta no está clara porque has de añadir más informacion de tu **problema exacto**. Has investigado el uso de  `nth-child`?  Qué has probado y qué errrores has tenido? Mira el [tour] y [ask] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y como hacer mejores preguntas y de más calidad. un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
ul li:first-child, ul li:first-child + li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

También puedes intentar así:

```
ul li:nth-child(1), ul li:nth-child(2){
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: perfecto, la segunda manera me va genial. gracias!

Comment: Hola Armando, gracias por aportar. Ante preguntas con tan poca informacion  (del problema exacto que tiene) es mejor esperar a que el usuario edite la pregunta para aclararlo. No todas las preguntas se han de responder , o al menos no directamente. La proxima vez procura pedir en los comentarios bajo la pregunta una mejora de la misma. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, el ya indicó que mi respuesta le fue de ayuda, tendré en cuenta tu recomendación de igual manera.

Comment: @Jonatan valora la respuesta de Armando como la correcta. Es el mejor modo de agradecimiento en esta comunidad.